# Second Activity's' button jump back to Main Activity which it shouldn't be

Tags: java, android

I am new at Android development for my final year project. I have encounter some problem that second activity which is Parent Login Activity Page submit button is not working well as it should be done error checking before moving to another activity page.

**Main Activity.java code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
//DEFINE WHICH BUTTON TO CLICK ON
Button ButtonParent;
Button ButtonKid;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ButtonParent=findViewById(R.id.buttonParent);
    ButtonKid=findViewById(R.id.buttonKid);
    ButtonParent.setOnClickListener(this);
    ButtonKid.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view==ButtonParent) {
            Intent intent_Parent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ParentLogin.class);
            intent_Parent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent_Parent);
        }else if(view==ButtonKid) {
            Intent intent_Kid = new Intent(MainActivity.this, KidLogin.class);
            intent_Kid.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent_Kid);
        }
    }
}
```

**Parent Login.java Code**

```
public class ParentLogin extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
EditText pName;
EditText pNRIC;
Button ParentLogin;
Button ParentRegister;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_parent_login);

    pName = findViewById(R.id.LoginParentName);
    pNRIC = findViewById(R.id.ParentNRIC);

    ParentLogin=findViewById(R.id.LoginParentSubmit);
    ParentRegister=findViewById(R.id.LoginParentRegister);
    ParentLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    ParentRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == ParentLogin) {

        String ParentName = pName.getText().toString().trim();
        String ParentNRIC = pNRIC.getText().toString().trim();
        boolean res = ParentDAO.checkParent(ParentName, ParentNRIC);
        if ((TextUtils.isEmpty(ParentName))||!(TextUtils.isEmpty(ParentNRIC))) {
            Toast toast= Toast.makeText(ParentLogin.this, "Please fill in all the empty columns which are available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL,0,0);
            toast.show();

        } else {
            if (res) {
                Toast.makeText(ParentLogin.this, "Login Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent_parentActivity = new Intent(ParentLogin.this, ParentActivity.class);
                intent_parentActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent_parentActivity);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ParentLogin.this, "Login not Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }else if(view==ParentRegister) {
        Intent intent_parentRegister = new Intent(ParentLogin.this, ParentRegistration.class);
        intent_parentRegister.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent_parentRegister);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: As you are saying that activity changing without checking errors, so check conditions before starting new activity like: --> if (view==ButtonParent) {} ,   it should be  -->  if(view.getid() == R.id.buttonId)

Comment: @vikassemwal Or if it possible for you to review my whole code for android app?

Comment: ok i can do that contact me on - vikas.semwal1994@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two way to do it.

1.

```
finish();
```

`finish` command finishes your activity where you are. I mean if you are in activity a and you set a intent to go to activity b. So, if set finish() command below intent than if you press back button than you won't be redirect to activity a.

**Note : if there's an activity before activity a. So, you will be redirect to that activity. if you use finish command**

2.

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

It clears all of your activity.

Comment: so finish(); command will indicate that the end action of particular activity that will be terminated after performing all action told to be done?

Comment: @MooZhenCong it tells to finish the activity

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)` to:

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying that activity changing without checking errors, so check conditions before starting new activity

1. you can do debugging if you know how to do
2. Otherwise easy option is put **Log.e("check ","--1");** statements in each single line during whole condition you will find the corrupted line code

Check this condition

```
if ((TextUtils.isEmpty(ParentName))||!(TextUtils.isEmpty(ParentNRIC)))
```

Comment: yes, but not only it does not do error checking it also went back to the main activity page which is not defined in the code

Comment: ok you first need to understand where exactly the error is,,, and which line is throwing error than we can proceed

Comment: and mostly i think you should be having any syntax error, so check and tell me which activity and which line it is

Comment: i have updated answer check this condition there is some problem somewhere in this condition

Comment: yes , i have found out most of the answer in stackoverflow it said that  error on (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonParent); however it show me "Casting 'findViewById(...)' to 'Button' is redundant " after i adding this command.

Comment: now we don't have to give (Button) to findviewbyid now because of update it automatically works

Comment: have you checked this part --> if ((TextUtils.isEmpty(ParentName))||!(TextUtils.isEmpty(ParentNRIC)))

Comment: i think --> ! have to put inside (!TextUtils.isEmpty(ParentNRIC))